# Why does my program have an infinite-loop when I enter in a character?

Tags: c++, character, infinite-loop, do-while

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char replay;
    int userInput;
    cout<< "Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors"<<endl;
  do
 { 
    cout<<"Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors"<< endl;
    cin>> userInput;

    switch(userInput)
    {
      case 1:
      cout <<"You chose rock" << endl;
      break;

      case 2:
      cout <<"You chose paper" <<endl;
      break;

      case 3:
      cout <<"You chose scissors" << endl;
      break;

      default:
      cout << userInput << " is not a valid choice"<< endl;
      break;
   }  
    cout<<"Would you like to play again (Y for yes, N for no)?"<<endl;
    cin >> replay;
 }  while((replay=='Y') || (replay=='y')); 

    return 0; 

 }
```

When I enter in a character in my answer for entering a number and when I'm asked if I want to play again and I enter in a character that isn't Y, y, N, or n it goes into an infinite loop

Comment: What compile are you using as I cannot reproduce it under VS2010, even in http://ideone.com/C88qG3?

Comment: @herohuyongtao g++ and Im doing it in terminal

Answer (score 3):

`userInput` is defined as an `int`.  When you attempt to read an `int`, and what is actually in the stream is a `char`, it will fail (but the `char` is still in the buffer).  You must clear the error status and ignore the bad input:

```
if (!(cin >> userInput))
{
    cin.clear(); // clears the error state
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // remove the bad input from the buffer
}
else
{
    // the code if the input was valid
}
```

Comment: I haven't gone that far into coding to use this code in my code. I just need to know where my loop is, so I can fix it

Comment: That **is** what is causing your infinite loop.  You have invalid input, so when you do your while condition, it does not stop the loop, sends it to the top of the loop, input is already in the buffer, so it repeats ... forever.

Comment: If i declare userInput as "char userInput" i still get an infinte loop

Comment: @user2988803 Just use the code that Zac suggested and keep the other part of the code as it is. No need of changing userInput to char. Your cin statement has to be inside the if condition, that's all

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, but I would rearrange your code as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char replay;
    char userInputChar;
    int userInput;
    cout<< "Let's play Rock, Paper, Scissors"<<endl;
    for(;;)
    { 
        cout << "Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors"<< endl;
        cin >> userInputChar;

        userInput = userInputChar - '0';

        switch(userInput)
        {
            case 1:
            cout <<"You chose rock" << endl;
            break;

            case 2:
            cout <<"You chose paper" <<endl;
            break;

            case 3:
            cout <<"You chose scissors" << endl;
            break;

            default:
            cout << userInput << " is not a valid choice"<< endl;
            break;
        }  
        cout<<"Would you like to play again (Y for yes, N for no)?"<<endl;
        cin >> replay;

        if((replay!='Y') || (replay!='y'))
            break;
    } 

    return 0; 

 }
```

Notice how I took care of converting the `char` input to an `int`.

If you want to use your current loop declare `userInput` as a `char` and then make your switch statement like this: `switch(userInput - '0')`

Comment: I haven't gone that far into coding to use this code in my code. I just need to know where my loop is, so I can fix it

Comment: I made the edits but Im unable to exit the program after it asks me if i want to play again...like i would enter N or n and I cant exit the program

Comment: @user2988803 Try the if condition I used in my code.

Comment: when I put in Y or y...It doesn't replay the game

Comment: IM also using a g++ compiler and im doing it in terminal